# How can I effectively destroy a form that contains a TEdgeBrowser while it is loading?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a use case of `TEdgeBrowser` in Delphi 11 which is completely broken.

I'm hovering the mouse over a button, and when a certain amount of time passes, it displays a dynamically created window which has a `TEdgeBrowser`.  The latter will display the content with the call of `Navigate()`.  If I move the mouse away from my button area, I stop navigation and destroy the window.

Sometimes I have an Access Violation in `ntdll.dll` and it stops on `TEdgeBrowser` is finalizing the creation of its environment.

I understood that the `TEdgeBrowser` is returning control to the window, except that it's too late.

I try to delay loading the browser as much as possible by avoiding processing messages and sleep, but once in 10, and especially when I hover the mouse quickly over my button to trigger the described navigation process, I get the Access violation.

That's the first problem, but it is less harmful than the second which is very serious: once I have this blockage, I can no longer load any `TEdgeBrowser` browser in my application. I use it everywhere and each time, I have empty content of the page, pdf, or file to load by calling `Navigate()`.

I can't find any serious solutions for this problem, which is starting to persist.

How can I delay the destruction of the file until the browser is initialized?

Here is the code for the main form

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, FormHelp;

type
  TMain = class(TForm)
    BitBtnHelp1: TBitBtn;
    BitBtnHelp2: TBitBtn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FHelpManager: THelpManager;
  public
  end;

var
  Main: TMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  FHelpManager := THelpManager.Create;
  For i:= ComponentCount-1 Downto 0 Do
  begin
    if (Components[i] Is TBitBtn) then
    begin
      TBitBtn(Components[i]).OnMouseLeave := FHelpManager.OnBitBtnMouseLeave;
      TBitBtn(Components[i]).OnMouseEnter := FHelpManager.OnBitBtnMouseEnter;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

and in this unit the code to manage the display

```
unit FormHelp;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Winapi.WebView2, Winapi.ActiveX,
  Vcl.Edge, VCL.ExtCtrls, VCL.Buttons;

const
  CM_HTMLNAVIGATE = WM_USER + $1001;

type
  THelpForm = class;

  THelpManager = class
  private
    FHelpForm: THelpForm;
    FTimer: TTimer;
    FHelpFileName: String;
    procedure FireTimerTreatment();
  public
    procedure   OnBitBtnMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure   OnBitBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure   OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
    constructor Create();
  end;

  THelpForm = class(TForm)
    Browser: TEdgeBrowser;
    procedure BrowserCreateWebViewCompleted(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser;
      AResult: HRESULT);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
  protected
    FHelpFileNameToLoad:string;
    FIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated: Boolean;
    procedure DoNavigation(var Message: TMessage);  message CM_HTMLNAVIGATE;
    procedure SetIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated(AValue: Boolean);
    function  GetIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated(): Boolean;
  public
    property  IsWebViewOfBrowserCreated: Boolean read GetIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated write SetIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated default False;
    procedure Show(AFileName: String); reintroduce;
  end;

var
  HelpForm: THelpForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Uses System.UITypes;

{ THandleHelp }

constructor THelpManager.Create();
begin
  FHelpForm := Nil;
  FTimer := Nil;
  FHelpFileName := '';
end;

procedure THelpManager.OnBitBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not(Sender is TBitBtn) then
    Exit
  else begin
    If (TBitBtn(Sender).Tag=1) Then
      FHelpFileName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName))+'Aide\MyFile1.html'
    else if (TBitBtn(Sender).Tag=2) Then
      FHelpFileName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName))+'Aide\MyFile2.pdf';
  end;

  if (FTimer<>Nil) then
  begin
    FTimer.Enabled := True;
    Exit;
  end else begin
    FTimer := TTimer.Create(nil);
    FTimer.Interval := 800;
    FTimer.Enabled := True;
    FTimer.OnTimer := OnTimer;
  end;
end;

procedure THelpManager.OnBitBtnMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (Sender is TBitBtn) then
    Exit;

  if FHelpForm<>nil then
  Begin
    var counter: Integer := 0;
    While ((not FHelpForm.IsWebViewOfBrowserCreated) or
          (FHelpForm.Browser.BrowserControlState = TCustomEdgeBrowser.TBrowserControlState.Creating) or
          (FHelpForm.Browser.WebViewCreated=False)) and (counter<99) do
    Begin
      Inc(counter);
    End;
  End;

  if FTimer<>nil then
    FreeAndNil(FTimer);

  if FHelpForm<>nil then
  begin
    FHelpForm.Close;
    FHelpForm := Nil;
  end;
end;

procedure THelpManager.FireTimerTreatment;
begin
  if (FHelpForm<>nil) and (FHelpForm.Showing) then
    Exit;

  if (FHelpForm=nil) then
    FHelpForm := THelpForm.Create(Nil);

  if (FileExists(FHelpFileName) = false)  then
  begin
    MessageDlg('No help file was found !', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  FHelpForm.Show(FHelpFileName);
end;

procedure THelpManager.OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTimer.Enabled := False;
  FireTimerTreatment();
end;

procedure THelpForm.BrowserCreateWebViewCompleted(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser;
  AResult: HRESULT);
begin
  FIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated := True;
end;

procedure THelpForm.DoNavigation(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Browser.Navigate(FHelpFileNameToLoad);
end;

procedure THelpForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure THelpForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Self.handle, CM_HTMLNAVIGATE, 0, 0);
end;

function THelpForm.GetIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated;
end;

procedure THelpForm.SetIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated(AValue: Boolean);
begin
  FIsWebViewOfBrowserCreated := AValue;
end;

procedure THelpForm.Show(AFileName: String);
begin
  FHelpFileNameToLoad := AFileName;
  Position := TPosition.poMainFormCenter;
  inherited Show;
end;

end.
```

by hovering the mouse gently over one of the 2 buttons and especially when the HelpForm is being drawn, I have an access violation. Note: if I increase the interval of my counter, I will have less of the problem and if I decrease it, I will have more of the error

```
the call stack is like this (with madExcept)
exception number   : 1
exception class    : EAccessViolation
exception message  : Violation d'accès à l'adresse 7757F603 dans le module 'ntdll.dll'. Ecriture de l'adresse 00000014.

main thread ($4340):
7757f603 +93 ntdll.dll
7755ff74 +44 ntdll.dll                              RtlEnterCriticalSection
00ac252f +0b Project1.exe System.SyncObjs  1104  +1 TCriticalSection.Acquire
00b863b7 +0f Project1.exe Vcl.Edge         1709  +1 TCustomEdgeBrowser.ProcessHResult
00b8532e +52 Project1.exe Vcl.Edge         1039  +2 TCustomEdgeBrowser.CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompleted
00b89075 +11 Project1.exe Vcl.Edge          834  +1 {Vcl.Edge}Callback`2.CreateAs[3]$ActRec<System.HRESULT,Winapi.WebView2.ICoreWebView2Controller,Winapi.WebView2.ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>.$0$Body
76915b0b +0b USER32.dll                             DispatchMessageW
00b6d3d7 +f3 Project1.exe Vcl.Forms       11488 +23 TApplication.ProcessMessage
00b6d41a +0a Project1.exe Vcl.Forms       11518  +1 TApplication.HandleMessage
00b6d759 +d1 Project1.exe Vcl.Forms       11657 +27 TApplication.Run
00b93e11 +49 Project1.exe Project1           19  +4 initialization
7717fcc7 +17 KERNEL32.DLL                           BaseThreadInitThunk
```

When I get this error, if I hover the mouse over any button again, I have the window that appears, the browser container that is there but is empty.

Comment: Keep a TEdgeBrowser instance around instead of constantly creating/destroying an instance.